# "Multiple build commands for output file" warning for .h files with the same name in different folders

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, build

I'm using **Xcode** 8.3.1 and **CocoaPods** 1.2.0 to check out and build **GoogleProtobuf** 2.6.1 project.

The issue is that **GoogleProtobuf** has 2 header files named `package_info.h` in 2 different folders:

1. `src/google/protobuf/package_info.h`
2. `src/google/protobuf/io/package_info.h`

Because of this, Xcode generates warning during the build:

> Warning: Multiple build commands for output file
>   /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-bkyudqdudbvdcaggnrpbojxmcruf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleProtobuf/package_info.h

Since my  **GoogleProtobuf** Xcode project is fully generated by **CocoaPods**, I'd rather not to change anything by hands in the generated files.

How do we suppose to deal with the warning in this situation? Can we disable this warning? Do we have some **CocoaPods** setting to generate the project differently?

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the build for some reason wants to copy all header files (from multiple directories) into one output directory. This doesn't seem very useful -- the headers are not usable if they've lost their directory structure. So it seems the build is doing something useless here, even aside from the warning. Maybe you can somehow tell it _not_ to copy headers around?

Comment: @KentonVarda: This might be the case - all source files of the GoogleProtobuf project look as they are all in the one folder in Xcode's Project Navigator. Can this be the root cause of the issue?

Comment: @KentonVarda: And regarding not to copy headers around - if I do this so, will the build produce the correct output then? GoogleProtobuf is part of the static lib used by another project of the workspace in my case.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about Xcode nor CocoaPods. But it sure looks like it's doing something broken here.